# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'linarg'?

Tags: python, numpy

下記のようなプログラムを実行したところ,

```
# coding: utf-8


import numpy as np

def cos_sim(v1,v2):
    return np.dot(v1,v2) / (np.linarg.norm(v1) * np.linarg.norm(v2))


x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
y = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
z = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

print(cos_sim(x, y))
print(cos_sim(y, z))
print(cos_sim(z, x))
```

以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/komaaaaaaari/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(cos_sim(x, y))
  File "C:/Users/komaaaaaaari/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 7, in cos_sim
    return np.dot(v1,v2) / (np.linarg.norm(v1) * np.linarg.norm(v2))
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'linarg'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

類似の例を見てnumpyの再インストールは行ったのですが解決できず、お力をお借りしたいです。pythonは詳しくないためさっぱりです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

名前としてご指定の `linarg` は `linalg` (線形代数 = LINear ALGebra)の間違いです。
`linalg` は線形代数学で定義される各種操作を持っています。

`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'linarg'`

というエラーメッセージがあります。
これは `numpy` モジュールは `linarg` というアトリビュートを持っていませんという意味です。
つまり `linarg` の指定が怪しいということが読み取れます。

ここまで分かれば、その後のデバッグのコツとしては、

1. `linarg` という名称は本当に正しいであろうか？と疑ってみる
2. 正しいようであれば `linarg` を使う上では、何か特別な指定(特にパッケージのimportなど)をしなくてよいだろうか？

などを疑ってみるとよいでしょう。

Comment: くだらないミスで恐縮です。ありがとうございました。デバッグのコツについても丁寧にありがとうございます。銘肝致します。